# Expanding a range in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am in the process of putting together a Word macro (below) that parses a table of acronyms in one Word document and highlights every occurrence of these acronyms in another Word document. This appears to be functional.

However, I would like to also have the macro differentiate acronyms that are in parentheses from those that are not. For example,

The soldier is considered Away Without Leave (AWOL).  AWOL personnel are subject to arrest.

It seems as though the range "oRange" that defines the found acronym could be evaluated, if it is first expanded in the Do-While loop using this code:

oRange.SetRange Start:=oRange.Start - 1, End:=oRange.End + 1

However, none of my attempts to code a solution seem to work (they put the macro into an infinite loop or result in error messages). I'm fairly new to VBA programming and am obviously missing something regarding how the loops are operating.

My question is: is there a way to duplicate the range "oRange" for subsequent manipulation or is there some other method that I should be using?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

---

```
Sub HighlightAcronyms()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim oRow As Row
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim sCellText As String

Dim oDoc_Source As Document
Dim strListSep As String
Dim oRange As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim sCellExpanded As String

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strListSep = Application.International(wdListSeparator)

'*** Select acronym file and check that it contains one table

wdFileName = WordApplicationGetOpenFileName("*.docx", True, True)
If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & wdFileName & """ contains no tables.", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

        ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
             MsgBox "The file """ & wdFileName & """ contains multiple tables.", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    End If
End With

'*** steps through acronym column

wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
Selection.SelectColumn
For Each oCell In Selection.Cells
    ' Remove table cell markers from the text.
    sCellText = Left$(oCell.Range, Len(oCell.Range) - 2)
    sCellExpanded = "(" & sCellText & ")"
    n = 1
    'need to find foolproof method to select document for highlighting
    Documents(2).Activate
    Set oDoc_Source = ActiveDocument

    With oDoc_Source
        Set oRange = .Range
        With oRange.Find
            .Text = sCellText
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            Do While .Execute
                If n = 1 Then
                    oRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
                Else
                    oRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
       'trying to add code here to expand oRange and compare it to sCellExpanded
                n = n + 1
            Loop
        End With
    End With
Next oCell

Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I found one solution, which may be a kluge:                                                                                                                                     Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
myRange.SetRange Start:=oRange.Start - 1, End:=oRange.End + 1
If myRange = sCellExpanded Then
     oRange.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
End If

Answer (score 0):

Try This

1. Define two ranges instead of merging the `oRange`.

See this sample code (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strSearch As String, sCellExpanded As String
    Dim oRange As Range, newRange As Range

    strSearch = "AWOL"
    sCellExpanded = "(" & strSearch & ")"

    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    With oRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = strSearch
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

         Do While .Execute
            If n = 1 Then
                oRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
            Else
                oRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            End If

            '~~> To check if the found word is not the 1st word.
            If oRange.Start <> 0 Then
                Set newRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=oRange.Start - 1, End:=oRange.End + 1)
                If newRange.Text = sCellExpanded Then
                    '
                    '~~> Your code here
                    '
                    newRange.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
                End If
            End If
            n = n + 1
         Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

Unable to upload image at the moment. imgur server is down at the moment.

You may see this link

http://wikisend.com/download/141816/untitled.png

Comment: Can you host the image directly in stackoverflow? Some proxies block your link. Thanks